# Give an example of a non-compact set $X$ such that every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Give an example of a non-compact set $X$  such that every continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.

**My try**:

Consider $\Bbb N$ and the  metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.Now $(\Bbb N,d)$ is not compact but every continuous function will be uniformly continuous .

If $f$ is continuous then to show that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ ,I choose $\delta <1$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$

Is this example correct?Please help.

Comment: Yes that should work. The canonical example would probably be the discrete metric, where the distance from two distinct points is always $1$.

Comment: But the usual metric when restricted to $\Bbb N$ becomes the discrete metric...Right ??@ElliotG

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya discrete metric takes value $1$ and $0$ only, so no.

Comment: Sorry I mean to say discrete space

Comment: It's an ambiguous word since the integers are also discrete, but the discrete metric almost always refers to the metric with values zero and one, which isn't the same as restricting the Euclidean metric.